# Redux: dispatch function to store?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

How is it possible to save a function as state in redux store?

Example:

I pass a function as parameter to a redux-thunk dispatcher function and i want to save this filter function in my redux store:

```
export const SET_FILTERED_USERS = 'SET_FILTERED_USERS';

export function setFilteredUsers(filter) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const allUsers = getState().users.allUsers;
        const filteredUsers = allUsers.filter(filter);

        dispatch({
            type: SET_FILTERED_USERS,
            data: {
                filteredUsers,
                filter
            }
        });

        const activeUser = getState().users.activeUser;

        if (activeUser && !_.isEmpty(filteredUsers) && filteredUsers.indexOf(activeUser._id) === -1) {
            dispatch(setActiveUser(filteredUsers[0]));
        } else {
            dispatch(setActiveUser(allUsers[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

In ReduxDevTools i can see, "filter" is not dispatched and saved in store. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Update: my shortend reducer:

```
import {
    SET_FILTERED_USERS
} from '../actions/users';

import assign from 'object-assign';

export const initialState = {
    filter: null,
    filteredUsers: null
};

export default function (state = initialState, action = {}) {
    const {data, type} = action;

    switch (type) {
        case SET_FILTERED_USERS:
            return assign({}, state, {
                filteredUsers: data.filteredUsers,
                filter: data.filter
            });

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your reducer look like? There you should be able  to control what gets saved in the store.

Comment: don't save functions in your state, their not serializable, and that goes against the whole principal of redux.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel: ok, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @SebastienDaniel, did not know that either :-)

Answer (score 0):

As Sebastian Daniel said, don't do that.  Per the Redux FAQ, that breaks things like time-travel debugging, and is not how Redux is intended to be used: [Can I put functions, promises, or other non-serializable items in my store state?](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state)

What you could consider as an alternative is storing some kind of description of the filtering you want.  As a sort of relevant example, in my current prototype, I'm creating a lookup table of dialog classes that I might want to show, and when I need to show one, I dispatch an action containing the name of the dialog type.  My dialog manager class pulls that "dialogType" field out of state, uses that to look up the correct dialog component class, and renders it.

The other question, really, is why you actually want to store a function in your state in the first place.  I see what you're *trying* to do there, but not actually what you're hoping to accomplish with it.

Comment: What if the "function" is a cancelToken for a promise. Where would you store it ?

Comment: Depends. Where else do you need to access it?